# Get the_time (date actually) inside a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a loop that shows the latest posts. I want to change the part that says: `. get_comments_number($question->ID) .` and instead of that get the date. `(<?php the_time('F j, Y') ?>)`

This is the loop:

```
$loophtml = $loophtml . "<span class='list-number-answers'>" . get_comments_number($question->ID) . " comentarios</span>&nbsp;&#183;&nbsp<a href='" . get_permalink($question->ID) ."'>Comentar</a>";
```

I'm not sure how to add ($question->ID) to the_time. Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`get_the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time), it returns the time for a specific date:

```
get_the_time('F j, Y', $question->ID)
```

[`the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) can only be used in [*The Loop*](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).